# Producing Buffer Radius Polygons - Possible Projection Issue

Tags: python, geopandas, geoviews

I created a GeoDataFrame with a Points `geometry` column:

#### 1. Create `df`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[51.502687, -3.538329, 2242, 1, 47],
                   [52.699185, -0.050122, 870, 2, 35],
                   [51.574387, 0.397882, 651, 3, 47],
                   [51.43874, 0.395791, 625, 4, 35],
                   [51.23965, 0.561919, 614, 5, 36]],
                   columns = ["lat","long","num_of_trucks","performance","num_of_routes"]
                 )

df
```

#### 2. Create `gdf` from `df`

```py
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df["lat"],df["long"]),
                                                                 crs={"init": "epsg:4326"})
gdf
```

#### 3. Reproject to CRS that uses metres and calculate 10KM `buffer_radius` around each Point

```py
gdf.to_crs(epsg=3395,inplace=True)
#gdf.to_crs(epsg=3857,inplace=True)
#gdf.to_crs(epsg=27700,inplace=True)

gdf["buffer_radius"] = gdf.geometry.buffer(10000)
```

#### 4. Change Geometry column to new `buffer_radius` column

```py
gdf = gdf.set_geometry('buffer_radius')
gdf.geometry.name
```

```py
Out: 'buffer_radius'
```

The above process appeared to produce my desired GeoDataFrame `gdf` with a new "geometry" column called `buffer_radius` that contains Polygons.

I then wanted to plot these newly created Polygons, so first I converted the CRS of the `buffer_radius` column:

#### 5. Reproject to CRS that allows me to produce plot:

```py
gdf.to_crs(epsg=4326,inplace=True)
```

#### 6. Produce final plot:

I then tried to plot the polygons however it returned an empty plot:

```py
gv.Polygons(gdf)
```

[image]

The fact that my plot returns empty made me wonder if it was a possible projection issue?

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here? Any thoughts or pointers would be massively appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently an issue with `geoviews`, which instead of using the active geometry column uses the default column called `geometry`. If you just override geometry column with your buffer (`gdf["geometry"] = gdf.geometry.buffer(10000)`) or make sure that the dataframe you want to plot has the geometry you want in geometry column, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the plotting issue. I'll edit the question to remove the second part and create a second question as the two issues that I am experiencing don't seem to be related.